# count function coincides with one of three criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need help with some logic's
In excel I have this table:

```
A                 B                      C
    status      left_term   loan_principal_after

    VALIDATED   19                575.48
    VALIDATED   18                740.24
    VALIDATED   2                 249.48
    VALIDATED   6                 796.66
    IDENTIFIED  21                603.76
    VALIDATED   2                  39.95
    IDENTIFIED  13                 730.32
    IDENTIFIED  20                2104.02
    IDENTIFIED  21                823.73
    VALIDATED   10                 20.63
    IDENTIFIED  20                 373.36
    VALIDATED   21                 464.45
```

I need count rows, by this criteria : left_term > 6 OR loan_principal_after > 300 OR status = VALIDATED

How should the formula be written if I want at least one of the criteria to match and count, like STATUS "Validated" OR LEFT_Term > 6 OR loan_principal_after > 300 ?

if VALIDATED, OR <300 OR <6m if at least one is true, then count

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243504/discussion-on-question-by-power-cat-count-function-coincides-with-one-of-three-c).

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH #1**

```
=SUM(BITOR(BITOR(--(A2:A13="VALIDATED"),--(B2:B13>6)),--(C2:C13>300)))
```

(structured table references)

```
=SUM(BITOR(BITOR(--(Table1[status]="VALIDATED"),
                 --(Table1[left_term]>6)),
           --(Table1[loan_principal_after]>300)))
```

Explanation:

- generate three arrays of 1s and 0s; one array for each of the criteria (e.g. "VALIDATED")
- use OR logic across the three arrays so that any criteria that passes will generate a 1 for that row (while *no criteria passed* in a row will generate a 0 for that row)
- unfortunately, `OR` doesn't seem to work on arrays (returns a single value), so I had to use `BITOR`
- unfortunately, `BITOR` only accepts two arguments, so I had to use two `BITOR`s to handle three ranges
- finally, sum up all the 1s generated by the passing rows

**APPROACH #2:** new MAP and LAMBDA functions

If you are using Excel as part of Microsoft 365 and have access to the newer functions, then you can use `MAP` and `LAMBDA`.

```
=SUM(--MAP(Table1[status],
           Table1[left_term],
           Table1[loan_principal_after],
           LAMBDA(a,b,c,OR(a="VALIDATED",b>6,c>300))))
```

Explanation:

- `MAP` returns array of `TRUE`s/`FALSE`s generated by the `LAMBDA`
- the `LAMBDA` accepts the 3 arrays (a, b, and c) as parameters and applies the **OR** logic to them
- the double-minus converts the array of `TRUE`/`FALSE`s to an array of 1s/0s
- `SUM` up the 1s and 0s into the final result

Note: text (e.g. "hello") is greater than any integer, so text in Column B or C will generate a false pass. Either you'll just have to make sure your Column B and C contains only clean data, or your formula should find some way to fail them if they are not numeric. So, you could either:

- check `ISNUMERIC` in the lambda and allow the other columns to be assessed, or
- you could try to coerce the Col B and C values to integer and fail the whole row if either fails e.g.

  ```
  =SUM(MAP(A2:A13,B2:B13,C2:C13,
       LAMBDA(a,b,c,
              --IFERROR(OR(a="VALIDATED",(b*1)>6,(c*1)>300),0))))
  ```

Comment: the answer would probably work even without the "--"s (double minus signs), so you can experiment with that if you want